# How to get a specific element with javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change a button's `backgroud-color` by using `JavaScript`.
Here is my button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-responsive btnVotePost" name="Approve" value="Approve" id="btnApprove{{post.postId}}" data-post-id="{{post.postId}}" onclick="approveClicked()">Approuver</button>
```

My template displays a list of buttons with identical characteristics except for `data-post-id` attribute.

So, the idea is to get `data-post-id`  in my `JavaScript` function and then change the button's `background-color`.

```
Function ApproveClicked(){
    var x = document.getAttribute("data-post-id")//Not working
}
```

So how do I get the value of `data-post-id` ?

Comment: Why don't you just use an external event handler and use the `this` reference so you don't have to work with a wonky CSS selector?

Comment: Well no, the document doesn't have that attribute. You need the element before you can get a data attribute on that element. Are you trying to *find* an element based on the ID? Or do you just want to access the element that was clicked inside its click handler (which is mis-named here)?

Comment: [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: Dynamic ids are somewhat a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is CaSe SeNsItIvE. `Function` is not the same as `function`. `ApproveClicked` is also not the same as `approveClicked`. This is the easiest way to get the data from your current element:

```js
function approveClicked(obj) {
    console.log(obj.dataset.postId);

    //You can then get the other element by id (Not recommended, as there are much better solutions, that don't pollute your DOM with id's like 1, 2, 3...):
    //document.getElementById(obj.dataset.postId).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-responsive btnVotePost" name="Approve" value="Approve" id="btnApprove{{post.postId}}" data-post-id="testId" onclick="approveClicked(this)">Approuver</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it following way. Also you made few mistake on type issue, such as you wrote `Function` it should `function`, function name also mismatch you wrote in button attribute `approveClicked` but in declaration you wrote `ApproveClicked`.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-responsive btnVotePost" name="Approve" value="Approve" id="btnApprove{{post.postId}}" data-post-id="{{post.postId}}" onclick="approveClicked(this)">Approuver</button>

function approveClicked(self){
  var x = self.getAttribute("data-post-id")
}
```